# jQuery Not allowed to load local resource

Tags: jquery

This is the part of the script for getting the image

```
//Document.ready image load
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                dataType: "json",
                url: "@Url.Action("FirstImage", "Home")",
                success: function (jsonData) {
                    //Insert new image to the slide
                    newImg = $("<img />");

                    newImg.attr("data-id", jsonData.nextImage.id);
                    newImg.attr("data-catpos", jsonData.nextImage.categoryPosition);
                    newImg.attr("data-rateamount",  jsonData.nextImage.amountOfRates);
                    newImg.attr("data-avg", jsonData.nextImage.rating);
                    newImg.attr("src", jsonData.nextImage.src);
                    newImg.attr("alt", "No image");

                    $(".slide").html(newImg);

                    console.log(jsonData.nextImage.src);
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("Error getting next image");
                }
            });
        });
```

This is what the console.log in the code above writes
C:\Users\jim\Dropbox\egne projekter\rateme\rateme\Content\UploadedImages\e630c24c-cb39-49a0-8356-7eb192d8f348.jpg

How come that i get the following exception from chrome?? Not allowed to load local resource

Comment: try file:///c:\user...........

Comment: there needs to be a relative path to that image, not an absolute one. Something like `../Content/UploadedImages/e630c24c-cb39-49a0-8356-7eb192d8f348.jpg`. You can do this in MVC which appears to be what you're using.

Comment: @roryok
But dosen't this return a relative path to the image? System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("/Content/UploadedImages/"), imageFileName + imageExtension);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your application is referencing your resources by a file system path (C:\Users\jim\Dropbox\egne projekter\rateme\rateme\Content\UploadedImages\e630c24c-cb39-49a0-8356-7eb192d8f348.jpg). Jquery doesn't have access to your local file system. I would like an http server is spun up for your resources, so the urls will look something like http://127.0.0.1:1234/myApplication/Content/UploadedImages/e630c24c-cb39-49a0-8356-7eb192d8f348.jpg. Hope can get a bit help.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome and chromium automaticaly blocks AJAX requests from file:// protocol for security (?) reasons.

[This](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=40787&q=ajax%20local&colspec=ID%20Stars%20Pri%20Area%20Feature%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Modified%20Owner%20Mstone%20OS) is what google says about this case.