# PHP Not allowed to load local resource

Tags: php, download

I am not sure why I am getting the following error:

```
Not allowed to load local resource: file:///D:/CargoDocsPDFs/0000024606//NAM3112358.pdf
```

I am using the function below to create a table with links to pdf files a user can simply click to download:

```
<?php
function return401KDocs()
{
$dir = "D:/CargoDocsPDFs/0000024606/";
$ffs = scandir($dir);

echo "<table class='table table-bordered display nowrap'>";
echo "<thead>";
echo "<tr>
        <th style='width:300px;'>File Name</th>
        <th style='width:100px;'>Upload Date</th>
        <th style='width:25px;'>File Size</th>
        <th style='width:100px;'>Delete</th>
      </tr>";
echo "</thead>";
echo "<tbody>";
foreach($ffs as $ff)
{
    if($ff != '.' && $ff != '..' && preg_match('#(pdf|doc|docx|xls|xlsx|PDF)$#',$ff))
    {                       
        $filesize = filesize($dir . '/' . $ff); 
        echo "<tr><td><a download href='$dir/$ff'>$ff</a></td><td>" . 
        date('m.d.y - g:i A', filemtime($dir . '/' . $ff)) . 
        "</td><td>" . round(($filesize / 1024), 2) . " kb</td>
        <td><a href='#' class='delete401KFile' data-file='".$ff."'>Delete</a></td></tr>";
    }
}
echo "</tbody>";
echo "</table>";
}    
?>
```

Using the above function prints out a table, and the available files are links that a user should be able to click to download the file.  But I am prohibited by the subject error message.

I found this link: [jQuery Not allowed to load local resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27980556/jquery-not-allowed-to-load-local-resource)

But I cannot use that link as it is in regards to using an AJAX call.  I am trying to accomplish this task with PHP.

Comment: Maybe it's the extra `/` in `file:///D:/CargoDocsPDFs/0000024606//NAM3112358.pdf`. So `$filesize = filesize($dir . '/' . $ff);` should be `$filesize = filesize($dir . $ff); `

Comment: @HansWassink - No luck, only receiving the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made an answer coz wasn't able to comment because of the points, so please don't negative vote.

You shouldn't load files off a local filesystem. You need to have it hosted with your app and load it off the web server.

You will never be able to directly display files on the client that are in your storage folder (C or D drives). The only thing browsers can actually get at are:

1. The things that are actually underneath the public folder
2. The code that is called through index.php (your app)

So, you would need to store your files somewhere in the public folder (of the server)

You can get some help with this link: 
https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/53870/cannot-load-local-resource

Comment: I never downvote anyone.  And if I did, I would at least provide an explanation as to why I downvoted them.  In regards to your answer, our webfiles are indeed on 
 the C: drive, but the PDF files need to be uploaded and saved into the D: drive.  Are you saying this is impossible to do or ill-advised?

Comment: It is ill-advised and shouldn't be done because you arfe trying to access absolute paths & also you cannot refer to the server drives actually, unless its linux and you are mounting the drive to server (that too will need a different code altogether) which in this case is not the question precisely.

Also i don't understand why you want to write & read files from & to to the drives directly, create a public folder in web-app (the root folder of your project that stays in htdocs if xampp is used) & store the PDF's there giving unique id to each & every file & then you are good to go

Answer (score 0):

Instead of referencing a local file path like "C:\AppServ\www\photo\1.jpg," you should reference the file using a URL when working on a local server.
Don't use this -> C:\AppServ\www\yourphotolocation\photo.jpg
Use this instead -> http://localhost/yourfilelocation